# Shortest command to extract a submatrix using a vector containing the indexes of the 2 corners [matlab]

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Let's say we have the following matrix

```
A=magic(4)

16     2     3    13
 5    11    10     8
 9     7     6    12
 4    14    15     1
```

and we want to extract 3 submatrices, identified by the indexes for top left and bottom right corners. The indexes for a submatrix are contained in a row of the matrix `i`; columns 1 and 2 of `i` are the row indexes of the corners, columns 3 and 4 of `i` are the column indexes of the corners.

i.e.

```
i =

 1     1     1     3
 2     4     1     2
 3     4     3     4

>> A(i(1,1):i(1,2),i(1,3):i(1,4))

ans =

16     2     3

>> A(i(2,1):i(2,2),i(2,3):i(2,4))

ans =

 5    11
 9     7
 4    14

>> A(i(3,1):i(3,2),i(3,3):i(3,4))

ans =

     6    12
    15     1
```

The command `A(i(,):i(,),i(,):i(,))` which I used to extract the submatrices is not very convenient, so I wonder is there a better way to do the job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to type it all out then why not write a wrapper function?

```
A = magic(4);
S = @(r) A(i(r,1):i(r,2),i(r,3):i(r,4));
S(1)
S(2)
S(3)
```

If `A` may change after the definition of `S` then you would need to make it a parameter to the function.

```
S = @(A,r) A(i(r,1):i(r,2),i(r,3):i(r,4));
A = magic(4)
S(A,1)
S(A,2)
S(A,3)
```

Similarly if `i` may change then you would need to make it a parameter as well.

**Edit**
Unfortunately, contrary to my comment, if you want to perform assignment then `A(I(r))` won't work exactly the same as what you've posted since this always returns an array instead of a matrix. One possible workaround is to use cell arrays in place of comma-separated-lists, but this isn't as elegant as the read only option. For example

```
S = @(r) {i(r,1):i(r,2) , i(r,3):i(r,4)};
s = S(1); A(s{:})
s = S(2); A(s{:})
s = S(3); A(s{:})
```

Following the same principle you could pre-define a cell array from `i` to make access one line.

```
s = arrayfun(@(r) {i(r,1):i(r,2),i(r,3):i(r,4)}, 1:size(i,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
A(s{1}{:})
A(s{2}{:})
A(s{3}{:})
```

Comment: oh this is very good, simple and practical, thank you very much!

Comment: oh wait, why I can do for example `A(i(1,1):i(1,2),i(1,3):i(1,4))=-1` but not `S(A,1)=-1` ? It gives the error `Conversion to function_handle from double is not
possible.`

Comment: ah maybe because when I use the full command I'm modifying directly the matrix A, but when I use the function I'm not modifying A, right?

Comment: Yes this won't work for assignment. You could define a function that returns the indicies of interest, then you could use `A(I(1))=1` where `I=@(r) sub2ind(size(A), ...)`. I'm on my phone now but I'll come back and add a complete answer later.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, what a pity. I think I'll use the full command only in the assignement, and the wrapper function in the other cases.

Comment: @soundwave I added one option which may be a bit more usable.